# I want to insert this into the database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into tblemp (Empno, Ename, Salary) 
values('3', '[hgh''//?||']', '1234')
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ']'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Comment: A ' inside a string literal should be doubled, i.e. '[hgh''//?||'']'

Comment: @jarlh **must**, not **should**.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's not optional...

Answer (score 4):

The string `[hgh''//?||']` contains single quotes that must be quoted (i.e. doubled, so the SQL engine knows you really want a `'` character), otherwise they are interpreted as the string delimiter.

Your query is interpreted as follows: The string `[hgh'//?||` should be inserted (the following `'` ends the string), but then there's a `]` that shouldn't be there. Also the `'` after the `]` starts a new string that doesn't end. The SQL engine doesn't know how to handle that, as it is not valid SQL.

To insert this value `[hgh''//?||']` literally into a column, you need to write

```
insert into tblemp(Empno,Ename,Salary) values('3','[hgh''''//?||'']','1234');
```

Comment: Insert into accnoti(AccountID,Action,Module,SqlTrans) 
values('1000002','Deleted','Advertiser_Home.aspx','[update Campaign set CampaignStatus='3' where AdvertiserID='1000002' and CampaignID='300146be-2534-471f-b90e-f9ffa1776031']')

Comment: It shows me :.....Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')@Thoresten Dittermar

Comment: Did you understand my answer or did you just copy & paste the SQL code? The solution to that problem is *exactly the same* as to your original problem! If you want to insert single quotation marks into a table column, you have to **double them in your SQL statement**!

Answer (score 0):

Learn about "Escaping", for instance:

[Escaping SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/)

[Escaping C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this i already tested

```
insert into tblemp (Empno, Ename, Salary) 
values('3', '[hgh''''//?||'']', '1234')
```